# How to segue (push) from ViewController to another ViewController embedded in NavigationController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a tableView in a viewController and when I tap on a cell a push segue is performed to a navigation controller that is **embedded** in another viewController. In the swift file for the first VC I have `prepareForSegue` function firing when a cell is tapped and in that function I pass some info to a textView that is in the second viewController.

But when I run my app I get an error when I tap on a cell because I cast the destination VC as the second VC not the navigationController. But if I cast it as the navigationController instead, then the `segue` works but I cannot pass the info from the first VC to the textView in the second VC. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using storyboard ID for the destination view controller? Try to give a storyboard id to the navigation controller instead and then do your segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reach the Navigation Controller and get the topViewController from stack. This code snippet should be work.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifierIsHere" {

                    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController.navigationController?.topViewController as? YourClass
                    destinationVC. // do something.


            }
        }
```

**Second question answer is :**

You can get the indexPath like this;

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

and you can use `yourArray[indexPath.row]`

**Third question answer is;**

You **can not** directly set your textView.text in your prepareForSegue method. You should create a variable in your destionationViewController and you can send the data to this variable. Create a variable in your destionationViewController like this;

```
var journalText: String = ""
```

and now send the data in your prepareForSegue method.

```
destinationVC.journalText = "Some string"
```

Comment: That worked but now I'm getting an error message when I try to access the cell row number. I put `let selectedCell = sender as! UITableViewCell` "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x106ea03e8) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x106ea03c0)."

Comment: I updated my answer. Look the Second question answer is section and don't forget the accept my answer.

Comment: That also worked but now getting another error. `destinationViewController!.journalTextView.text = selectedEntry` "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". If I replace the ! with ? then no crash but textView is not updated.

Comment: Updated my answer. I answered your question so please accept my answer.